# How to type data as a relative address in Ghidra?

Tags: ghidra

A jump table I am reversing uses relative offsets to both data and functions. These relative offsets are 32-bit integers added to the address that the value is stored at. Does Ghidra support typing these as relative addresses for generating references (like how you can type a value as an absolute address by pressing <kbd>P</kbd>)?

For example:

```
                                 INT_00010f00                                            
           00010f00 49 ff ff ff       int          FFFFFF49h
```

Is actually a reference to `0x00010f00 + 0xffffff49 = 0x00010e49`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always set it manually to the specific address from the reference dialog (available under <kbd>R</kbd>). There you can providing the correct address calculated by adding `base address` and an `offset`. If you have more than one, you can automate it via `python` script.

I've recorded a video detailing such situation in action https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FvH7b_qLmbU